# Input value clears itself on focus?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, cordova

I've found that form inputs are clearing themselves on focus when building for iOS, but I do not have this problem in the browser. Example:

```
let PageBody = (
    <div>
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <br />
        <form>
            <p>Input: <input type="text" maxLength="100" name="someData" id="someData" /></p>
            <p><input type="button" id="SaveButton" name="SaveButton" value="Save" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
);
```

I believe this is happening at the JavaScript layer, because **adding an empty  onFocus="" resolves the issue**, preserving the value that was in the input.

Any thoughts on where this coming from or next steps in debugging?

**Edit:**

I removed the onFocus="" to continue tinkering and (frustratingly) I can no longer reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please provide a more complete example, with yours `onChange`, `onFocus` .etc events. Or your input is totally uncontrolled ?

Comment: That is the strange part, I have no event listeners on that field.

Comment: then, what is its purpose ? what do you want to perform with ? have you read differences between [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) and [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) inputs from React doc ?

Comment: Thank you! Will dig in, I suspect that was the missing link in my understanding.